# Need to create a fixed side banner/popup with AMP

Tags: amp-html

I need to create a small fixed side banner that is opened and has the option to be closed (as an with "X" button) but none of the AMP documentation components does not seem to have the functionality I seek, it should be a simple banner with a redirect on click on image and an "x" to close.

Can some one help? any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[Use AMP actions and events](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4yVlmiLklw) by adding an ID to the banner and then closing it with a button on tap.

Code:

```
<div id="banner">
<button on="tap:banner.hide">
  X
</button>
I am a banner 
<a href="#">
<amp-img src="someimage.png" width="200" height="200">

</amp-img>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, with my AMP "knowledge" that really helped, made a simple css+html thing for a banner!!!